# JInternalFrame repainting issue

Tags: java, jpanel, repaint, jinternalframe

Below code is my view where I get display a streaming camera. Controller handles sets the image and repaints the JInternalFrame. I have an issue with this because the camera image covers the whole JInternalFrame even the title bar. I tried using JPanel but I had problems getting the image on the JPanel because I extend JInternalFrame.

```
public class CameraView extends JInternalFrame{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public CameraView(){
        super("Camera", false,false,false, false);

        setSize(500,500);
        setLocation(200,200);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }


   public void setImage(BufferedImage image){
       this.image = image;
   }
}
```

This is what it looks like. No title bar.
[image]

Comment: You've overridden `paint` without calling `super.paint`, thereby preventing the `JInternalFrame` from having the opportunity to paint it's own decorations or other content.  Generally speaking, you should avoid overriding `paint` and instead prefer `paintComponent`, but in this case, you could just add a `JLabel` to the `JInternalFrame` and solve your problem entirly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the `paint` method of the frame. This `paint` method is what draws the title bar.

You should create a second class that extends `JComponent`, override the `paint` method on that class, and then add an instance of it to your frame.

Something like:

```
public class CameraView extends JInternalFrame{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public CameraView(){
        super("Camera", false,false,false, false);

        setLocation(200,200);

        add(new JComponent() {

            {
                setSize(500, 500); // size of the image
            }

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }

        });

        pack();
    }

   public void setImage(BufferedImage image){
       this.image = image;
   }
}
```

---

You could also have the `paint` method call `super.paint(g);` but the way you have it set up now, your image will overlay the title bar.

---

Also, calling `super("Camera", false,false,false, false);` is the same as calling `super("Camera")`. The defaults are `false`.

Comment: You just have used a `JLabel` :P